# Why laravel returns an empty array for a has many relationship?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb and i have schema is like below

Ticket Collection :

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("5f32d9bb486e94459b6531c3"),
      "subject": "\"URGENT\" Non-Compliance In (Eastern Region)",
      "content": "abc",
      "user_team": "5f044199e40dfe4847056785",
      "team_ids": [
        "5f3012bbb7c2bc422e4da5a2"
      ],
      "organization_id": "5f74359c7dcc8f6fbb2b47e2"
}
```

Team Collection :

```
{
      "_id":ObjectId("5f3012bbb7c2bc422e4da5a2"),
      "name": "Medical Maintenance",
      "createTickets": true
}
```

Relationship in Ticket Model :

```
public function teams()
    {
         return $this->HasMany('App\Team', 'team_ids');
    }
```

Relationship in Team Model :

```
public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ticket');
    }
```

I am facing an issue to get data for teams relationship. It return an emtpry array.

Laravel version is 6.2
jenssegers/mongodb version is 3.6

Comment: I am not sure but have your tried `return $this->HasMany('App\Team', 'team_ids', '_id');`

Comment: You defined the relationship completely wrong! How the Eloquent can find tickets by `team_ids` which is multiple and defined in an array structure?

Comment: @Jayant yeah i had tried but still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to the foreign key is wrong, when in the context of hasMany. Instead a single column called team_id should be on the ticket and then you can do the following.

```
public function teams()
{
     return $this->HasMany('App\Team', 'team_id');
}
```

Which would work if your ticket looks like so.

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("5f32d9bb486e94459b6531c3"),
      "subject": "\"URGENT\" Non-Compliance In (Eastern Region)",
      "content": "abc",
      "user_team": "5f044199e40dfe4847056785",
      "team_id":"5f3012bbb7c2bc422e4da5a2"
      "organization_id": "5f74359c7dcc8f6fbb2b47e2"
}
```

Instead it looks like you are actually doing a many to many, because one team can have many tickets and reverse. This can be defined like so, this will probably add the data to both models, but I'm not an expert on `Mongodb` in `Laravel`.

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Team::class, null, 'ticket_ids', 'team_ids'
    );
}
```

You can find all of this in the [documentation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#relationships).

Comment: i have more than 1 million tickets, if i store ticket_id in team collection then it will be huge single document of teams and i don't thinks so it is better approach, what you say?

Comment: It will be the same either way? but read the last part of the ticket.

Comment: no i have millions of ticket but team are few like 100 or 200

Comment: what do you mean by  "last part of ticket" ?

Comment: Last part of my answer, you can use that belongsToMany approach. That is how you designed it and that should work. Secondly i would never worry about foreign keys taking to much space. Unless they are unnecessary.

Comment: yeah i have already tries this approach and it is working and thanks for you detail answer brother .I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify foreign and local keys.

Example:

```
public function teams()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Team', 'team_ids', '_id')
}
```

Comment: i specify but it still return an emtpy