# Laravel+MongoDB eloquent relation not working

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, laravel-8, jenssegers-mongodb

I am new to MongoDB so pardon me if my approch is incorrect. I am building an application where I have created simple role and permission management. There are separate collections for permissions and roles. A role can have multiple permissions and those permissions can belongs to multiple role. typical many to many relationship.
I have embed permission in each Role collection as below.

**Role collection**

```
db.roles.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b6e6dca3b92759976e3037"),
    "role" : "Role 1",
    "permissions" : [
        "60b6e023a3b92759976e3033",
        "60b6e055550b3f41692caa2b",
        "60b6e07b550b3f41692caa2c"
    ],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T02:03:08.282Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T02:03:08.282Z")
}
```

**Permissions of same role**

```
> db.permissions.find({"_id":{"$in":[ObjectId("60b6e023a3b92759976e3033"), ObjectId("60b6e055550b3f41692caa2b"), ObjectId("60b6e07b550b3f41692caa2c")]}}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b6e023a3b92759976e3033"),
    "permission" : "product_listing",
    "label" : "Product Listing",
    "level" : 1,
    "parent" : null,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T01:45:22.287Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T01:45:22.287Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b6e055550b3f41692caa2b"),
    "permission" : "stock",
    "label" : "Stock",
    "level" : 2,
    "parent" : ObjectId("60b6e023a3b92759976e3033"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T01:45:22.287Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T01:45:22.287Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b6e07b550b3f41692caa2c"),
    "permission" : "previously_bought_icon",
    "label" : "Previously bought icon",
    "level" : 2,
    "parent" : ObjectId("60b6e023a3b92759976e3033"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T01:45:22.287Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-06-02T01:45:22.287Z")
}
```

Now I want something like below

`$role->permissions()`
should output all the permsion with details as shown above.

I tried belongsToMany, embedMany relationship but didn't work. Seems I am using wrong approch or I should pass some more fields to the elowuent relation. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please see this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761697/why-laravel-returns-an-empty-array-for-a-has-many-relationship/67765266

Comment: @hu7sy No luck. still getting empty result.
`{"withTimestamps":false}`

Comment: for many to many you have to store related id's in both collection

Comment: @hu7sy Hell yes, Thanks a ton. I was trying this one since last 4 hours. Finally could achive this. Well, I want to know is there any way where I can just  only add permissions in role collection  without adding roles in permission and still get the same result? I mean just asking

Comment: your question is valid but that is not possible brother

Comment: @hu7sy anyways. Thanks a lot